# Determine if all objects in a object are empty or null

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object that gets populated based off data from a file. I would like to know if the object that gets populated has empty objects for major and minor, and the properties in gpa are all set to null. Here is what the populated object would look like:

```
Bob Smith {
  major: {},
  minor: {},
  gpa: { freshman: null, sophomore: null, junior:   null }
}
```

I would like to know if all the objects in the bob smith object are empty so I can exit my program without doing all the logic after this.

*EDIT*
I was not as clear as I should have been before. It is not an all empty or all populated situation. There will be cases where some of the objects will have data, and some will not.
It is possible for Bob Smith to be populated like:

```
Bob Smith {
    major: { 
            department: 'Math'
           },
    minor: {},
    gpa: { freshman: 3.5, sophomore: null, junior: null }
}
```

In short, the Bob Smith object could have quite a few different combinations of non empty objects, I'm only looking for a way to quickly determine if major and minor are empty and gpa has values set to null. I have tried using ._isEmpty(), but have been getting hung up on the gpa object since it is not empty.

Comment: In your example, the `gpa` property is not empty. Does this need to be recursive? What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Your goal is unclear. As stated, the data will either be all null/empty or will all be populated. As stated, you simply have to test to see if `major` is empty or not. Please confirm or clarify your objective.

Comment: This: `BobSmith.major.entries().length` will provide your answer if the object is all empty this will return false, otherwise it will return an non-zero answer (equivalent of true).

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively iterate over the fields and see if they are all null:

```
function allNull(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !allNull(obj[key])) {
            return false;
        } else if (typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' && typeof obj[key] !== 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if the first nested returns false, no other siblings at. the same level will be tested. Likewise, it will return false early from the else as well without testing other siblings.

Comment: @RandyCasburn can you clarify your comment, please? I can't tell if you're praising or criticising

Comment: Meant as feedback only. Try your code, it won't recurse through the entire structure. In both cases it will return early (after the first finding of null/empty) and will stop testing at that point.  It will not recurse past the first null/empty essentially. (perhaps that is the goal, but we really don't know.) I've asked for clarification.

Comment: @RandyCasburn sorry for confusion, it's not my code but this only returns `false` early as that is indeed the goal, ie any non-null / non-empty value results in a `false` result. There's no point checking further, similar to `Array.prototype.some`

Comment: If that is indeed the goal, then recursion is unnecessary. The test is as simple as `BobSmith.major.entries().length`. The data structure is known too.